# sklearn kneighbours memory error python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, nearest-neighbor, knn

I am working on a Windows 7 8gb RAM.

This is the vectorizer I am using to vectorize a free text column in my 52MB training dataset

```
vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',stop_words='english',decode_error='ignore',binary=True)
```

I want to calculate 5 nearest neighbours with this dataset for an 18MB test set.

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5).fit(vec.transform(data['clean_sum']))
vectors = vec.transform(data_test['clean_sum'])
distances,indices = nbrs.kneighbors(vectors)
```

This is the stack trace -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cr_nearness.py", line 224, in <module>
    distances,indices = nbrs.kneighbors(vectors)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 371,
kneighbors
    n_jobs=n_jobs, squared=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 12
in pairwise_distances
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 10
in _parallel_pairwise
    return func(X, Y, **kwds)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 23
n euclidean_distances
    distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 181,
afe_sparse_dot
    ret = ret.toarray()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 940
 toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 250, in to
y
    B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 817, in _
ess_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using 32-Bit Python or 64-bit Python? Moving to 64-bit may resolve this problem.

Comment: I am using 64 bit in fact...

Comment: Hum...if you lower the number of neighbors (n_neighbors), you got the same problem? 

I'm actually doing something similar but with way more data and with multiple n_neighbors in a loop (like 1 to 9). I got a memory error by using Python 32 bit and I changed to Anaconda 64 bit and that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use KNN with KD TREE

> model =
>   KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='kd_tree').fit(X_train,
>   Y_train)

the model by default is algorithm='brute'. brute false take too much memory.
I think for your model it should be look like this

> nbrs =
>   NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='kd_tree').fit(vec.transform(data['clean_sum']))

Comment: [NearestNeighbors documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors) states that the brute force will always be used if the input is a sparse matrix. CountVectorizer returns sparse by default.

Comment: To densify a sparse matrix returned by CountVectorizer, use `.toarray()` method.